# Does the C++11 standard guarantee "n2 is int&" by "auto n2 = const_cast<int&>(n);"?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, type-systems, type-deduction

```
const int n = 0;
auto& n1 = const_cast<int&>(n);
auto n2 = const_cast<int&>(n);
```

Does the C++11 standard guarantee `n2 is int&` by `auto n2 = const_cast<int&>(n);`?

Must I use `auto& n1 = const_cast<int&>(n);` instead of `auto n2 = const_cast<int&>(n);`?

Are the two ways completely equivalent to each other as per the C++11 standard?

Comment: Pretty sure `n2` is `int`, without any ref. `auto` basically follows template argument deduction rules.

Comment: Do note that with C++14's `decltype(auto)` you can get the `decltype` rules to apply and you'll get your `int&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto` uses the same rules as regular function template argument deduction, which never deduces a reference.

C++14 `decltype(auto)`, on the other hand, can deduce a reference here. As well as C++11 `auto&&`.

```
const int n = 0;
auto a = const_cast<int&>(n);           // a is int
decltype(auto) b = const_cast<int&>(n); // b is int&
auto&& c = const_cast<int&>(n);         // c is int&
```

Answer (score 5):

`auto` on its own never produces a reference type.

So `n2` is an `int` type.

(If I had a dollar for every time I see code like `for (auto s : expensive_deep_copy_container)`).